# Is it possible to evaluate entire buffer in Emacs?

Tags: emacs

Currently, in order to evaluate elist in Emacs, I need to position the cursor on the last parenthesis and emit `C-x e`.

Is it possible to evaluate the entire buffer as a single elisp program without a need to position cursor?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

```
M-x eval-buffer
```

or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> and then type 'eval-buffer' or just type part of it and tab to autocomplete.

Answer (score 14):

I placed this in my `.emacs`!
It allows you to eval a region if there is one or the entire buffer.
I bound it to <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>E</kbd>.

```
(defun eval-region-or-buffer ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((debug-on-error t))
    (cond
     (mark-active
      (call-interactively 'eval-region)
      (message "Region evaluated!")
      (setq deactivate-mark t))
     (t
      (eval-buffer)
      (message "Buffer evaluated!")))))

(add-hook 'emacs-lisp-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            (local-set-key (kbd "C-x E") 'eval-region-or-buffer)))
```

Comment: From Clojure, I have `C-c C-k` (`cider-load-buffer`) burned into muscle memory, and it's not bound already in `emacs-lisp-mode-hook` so that's what I bind it to now.

Answer (score 0):

`C-c C-l` to load the entire file at once.