# Is it mandatory to evaluate a LISP variable before using it?

Tags: variables, lisp, elisp, eval

I'm new to ELISP and LISP in general.  Here's some example code:

```
(setq number 2)

(* 8 number)
```

In lisp interaction mode, I can use the key combination control+j at the end of a line and it should evaluate it inline.  If I try to do this at the second line of code `(* 2 number)`, I get an error message:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (void-variable number)
  (* 8 number)
```

My assumption is that `number` isn't registered as having a value.  If I perform control+j on the first line of code `(setq number 2)`, then I can use control+j on the second just fine.

**My question is, is my assumption that because the first value wasn't evaluated, the second one cannot be correct?  And also, is there a better way to register these values, in interactive mode, than to do it line by line?  I assume that when this application is ran normally, outside of being inside Emacs, this isn't an issue, just an issue when evaluating code on-the-fly inside Emacs.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What happens is that Elisp (and other Lisps like Common Lisp) generally evaluate forms. In this case, you have two forms, corresponding to your two lines.

```
(setq number 2)

(* 8 number)
```

Combination `C-j` specifically evaluates (and prints) a form. Another option that works, and which I tend to use is `C-x C-e` which evaluates the form preceding the cursor. That is, if you want to evaluate your `(setq number 2)`, you would place the cursor after the `)`.

To evaluate the entire buffer, you can use `M-x eval-buffer`. That will evaluate the entire thing you have written in the current buffer. For instance, your `number` variable would become "known" after that.

Also, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2518647/is-it-possible-to-evaluate-entire-buffer-in-emacs) question thread may be helpful to read.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you are correct.  As another answer says, lisps evaluate 'forms' and typically have two modes of operation:

- they can load files (or, historically, some other kinds of objects) which entails sequentially evaluating every top-level form in the file;
- you can interact with the lisp system conversationally, when it will evaluate the forms you type at it.

Emacs, and other Lisp environments, often also have support for pointing at one or more forms in a file (or buffer) and saying 'evaluate that'.  This has the problem that it may not be obvious exactly what has been evaluated and in what order.  Some systems keep track of this and let you say, for instance 'evaluate all the changed top-level forms in the buffer'.  Emacs does not have this natively, I think.

Three interactive Emacs functions may help you:

- `eval-region` will evaluate the forms in the region;
- `eval-buffer` will evaluate the whole buffer (as if you'd selected the whole buffer and said `eval-region`);
- `ielm` (which may not exist in all emacses, but I think does in anything recent) gets you an interactive elisp prompt, which you can type forms at for evaluation.

Answer (score 2):

To complete the answers (yes you have to `M-x eval-buffer` to run your entire lisp code), we can play a little bit with your variable `number`.

In Lisp `number` represents the stored **value**, whereas `'number` represents the variable "name" (or symbol).

For instance, `setq` is only a shortcut for `set quoted` because we want to affect a value to a symbol. These 3 lines are **equivalents**:

```
(setq number 8)
(set 'number 8)
(set (quote number) 8)
```

Then you can play with

```
(message (format "Result is %s" (* 8 number)))
(message (format "Result is %s" '(* 8 number)))
(message (format "Result is %s" `(* 8 ,number)))
```

Which prints:

```
Result is 64
Result is (* 8 number)
Result is (* 8 8)
```

Comments:

```
(* 8 number) : do the computation, you get a number

'(* 8 number) : keep unevaluated form

`(* 8 ,number) : evaluate number (notice the , char) then keep in an unevaluated form
```

One last thing, to unbound a value to a symbol just use

```
(makunbound 'number)
```

If you try now

```
(message (format "Result is %s" (* 8 number)))
```

you will get an error message:

```
Symbol’s value as variable is void: number
```

that confirms you that the symbol `number` is no longer bound to any value.

Comment: Note that `(setq x y)` and `(set 'x y)` are generally *not* equivalent in more modern Lisps than elisp.